# Music in Action script 3?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

Okay, so I am making a game (Actionscript 3) and I am trying to figure out how to stop the music when it reaches a screen. (Lose & Win) I do not know how to make it so that the music will pause when you lose or win.
     Here's what I have so far.

```
 var snd_SolidState = new SolidState();
snd_SolidState.play();
```

SolidState is the song. The Lose screen is on the 3rd frame. The win screen is on the 2nd. The symbol hosting the music is titled "Music". My problem is that whenever I win or lose and click "Play again" the song will repeat when the game starts again.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you press the "Play again" button, stop the music playing before it changes frame:

```
snd_SolidState.stop();
snd_SolidState = null;
```

Comment: Thanks! I am obviously new to coding, so I am not sure where to put the code. Here's the code for one of the buttons.              mc_again.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP,upAgain);
function upAgain(e:MouseEvent){
 gotoAndStop(1);
}

Comment: Put it before the line of "gotoAndStop(1);".

Comment: It is telling me that "stop" is not a function. I put up a more specific post.

Comment: The Sound object doesn't have a stop function; SoundChannel (returned by Sound.play()) does! The answer is incorrect.

Comment: Looks like my memory cheated on me. I am sorry, but I glad you got a proper answer in the re-post.